# Where to extend collection documents with computed fields in Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, database

We have information we need on the client which is computed on a document. Like for example the number of entries in an array.

More practically we have a document *Workshop* which helds an array of *participants* (user's _id). Now we want the *Workshop.numberOfParticipants()*.

There is no need to transmit the whole array to the client, so where to calculate this value? Is it possible to add this value to the document "Workshop" as a field like the other data?

I like to circumvent the generation of a Template.workshop.numberOfParticipants().

Answer (score 2):

One option for the future is MongoDB's oddly-named [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/).  Queries written against the `aggregate` API can return documents with calculated fields.

Meteor core doesn't support aggregate queries yet, but it's on the wishlist.

Comment: What is the state of this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to publish a set of documents called NumParticipants and then add an observer that updates a `count` property or something similar when documents are added (and similarly reduces that property when docs are removed).

An example of how to do this is described in the [documentation for publish](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish).

Comment: Rahul, this is a valid soultion for the use case described. I search but still for a possibility to do the calculation at query time and not up-front.